# Windows script to add static route for specific IP addresses

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to create specific routes from command prompt using a script.
For that, I need to know a specific address which I can use as a gateway.
I want to use this command:

`arp -a | findstr /i "a.b.c.d"`

Output will be:

`Interface: a.b.c.d --- 0x14`

Now, I want to modify this IP (by adding +1 at the last octet: so d+1) and make it a default gateway for other IPs (or subnets)

`route add x.y.z.w netmask 255.255.255.255 gateway a.b.c.d+1 metric 1`

Any idea how can I store retain the output from the initial command, and modify the IP address?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847871/how-to-split-an-ip-address-into-seperate-octets-and-perform-arithmetic-in-cmd

Comment: Are you asking how to get the IP addr from the `arp -a` output, or how to perform math on the IP addr after you have it?  The link above explains how to do the latter.  If it's the former, please clarify what you're trying to do; it seems like you already have the IP address for use in `findstr`, and don't need to parse it out again.

Answer (score 1):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set ipaddr=a.b.c.d

for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%a in ("%ipaddr%") do (
 set /a lastoctet = %%d + 1
 set "newipaddr=%%a.%%b.%%c.!lastoctet!"
)

route add x.y.z.w netmask 255.255.255.255 gateway %newipaddr% metric 1
```

This code uses a `FOR /F` to split the address into four parts, then uses `SET /A` to increment one of the parts, and then reassembles the address.  The code assumes you've already extracted the IP address (for use in the `findstr` command in your example.  You can use another `for /f` to parse out the IP address from the `arp` output.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%a in ('arp -a ^|findstr /i "Interface"') do set "ipaddr=%%a"
```

Note that the code above doesn't do any error handling.  When the last octet is > 254, the generated IP address will likely be invalid.  You should be able to add a check inside the `for` block to detect this condition.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, however, how do I extract only the IP address from the output if I know its pattern? For instance, I know it will start with fixed: a.b.c but dynamic d (a.b.c.d). Is there any way I can extract this from the output?

Comment: @alexsnemos Edited to add that in.

Answer (score 0):

This code can extract the ip adress and do the same thing as ***Ryan Bemrose*** has posted yet.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('arp -a ^|findstr /i "Interface"') do (set Data=%%a)
Call:ExtractIP "%Data%"
Echo The IP adress is : %IP%
pause
Setlocal Enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%a in ("%IP%") do (
 set /a lastoctet = %%d + 1
 set "newipaddr=%%a.%%b.%%c.!lastoctet!"
)
Echo route add x.y.z.w netmask 255.255.255.255 gateway %newipaddr% metric 1
EndLocal
pause
Exit /b
::**********************************************************************
:ExtractIP <Data>
(
    echo wscript.echo ExtractIP("%~1"^)
    echo Function ExtractIP(Data^)
    echo Set objRegex = new RegExp
    echo objRegex.Pattern = "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b"
    echo objRegex.Global = False
    echo objRegex.IgnoreCase = True
    echo Set Matches = objRegex.Execute(Data^)
    echo For Each Match in Matches   
    echo    ExtractIP = Match.Value
    echo Next
    echo End Function
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
For /f "delims=" %%# in ('Cscript /nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set IP=%%#
Exit /b
::**********************************************************************
```

***Edit :***
or more simple as Ryan Bemrose has posted in the comment to extract the IP adress :

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%a in ('arp -a ^|findstr /i "Interface"') do (set IP=%%a)
Echo The IP adress is : %IP%
pause
Setlocal Enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%a in ("%IP%") do (
 set /a lastoctet = %%d + 1
 set "newipaddr=%%a.%%b.%%c.!lastoctet!"
)
Echo route add x.y.z.w netmask 255.255.255.255 gateway %newipaddr% metric 1
EndLocal
pause
Exit /b
```

Comment: Unless you are concerned about validating the output of `arp`, there is no need to invoke a vbs file to parse the IP from the Interface line.  `for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%a in ('arp -a ^|findstr /i "Interface"') do set "IP=%%a"`

Comment: @RyanBemrose Thank you for your remark and i edit my answer based on it !